# Loading data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, octave

For my linear algebra class we must do projects where we are learning MATLAB. The second project involves taking a set of data and applying Cramer's Rule to it. I have already created a function, myCramerSolver, that works but the problem comes when I am loading the dataset that my professor gave us.

```
A = load ("A.mat");
b = load ("b.mat");
[x] = myCramerSolver(A,b);
x2 = A\b;
sum(x-x2)
```

MATLAB is constantly giving me errors regarding the loading process. I have tried implementing the other forms of loading(filename w/ variable, filename w/-mat etc.) to no avail. If anyone has any correction to my code, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try without space, so `load("A.mat");`? What error is MATLAB giving?

Comment: MATLAB gives me an error stating that the file is not found. I have made sure that the files are within the same folder so finding them should not be a problem, yet it is.

Comment: please post the exact error traceback.

Comment: add the output of `ls` before executing your script and the exact error message you get

Answer (score 0):

You could try if it works with uigetfile:

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.m', 'Select the MATLAB code file');
```